# Modify Excel file using python

Tags: python, excel

I have this excel file ,with common entries in first column ,how to remove the common entries in first column without affecting the rest of the file using python.

My file

```
 Column1   Column2             Column2
 PinkFloyd Wish You Were Here  Wish You Were Here
 PinkFloyd Comfortably Numb    The Wall
 AC_DC     Highway to Hell     Highway to Hell
 AC_DC     Thunderstruck       The Razors Edge
```

Required Output-

```
 Column1   Column2             Column3
 PinkFloyd Wish You Were Here  Wish You Were Here
           Comfortably Numb    The Wall
 AC_DC     Highway to Hell     Highway to Hell
           Thunderstruck       The Razors Edge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas`, specifically `pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('my_xls.xls')

# Find and drop duplicates in Column1
df['Column1'] = df.Column1.drop_duplicates()

# Open pandas ExcelWriter and write to *.xls file
with pd.ExcelWriter('my_xls.xls') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```